# Create message which is array of submessages?

Tags: ros2

Let's say I created a custom message in ROS2. How would I create a second meta message consisting of an array of those messages?

The documentation tutorial is very poor on creating anything but trivial messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically messages contain a timestamp and a reference frame. If one needs an array of data, that array is typically created inside the custom message. If one is looking to use a custom message type for multiple sensors or actuators, the ROS convention is to publish each sensor or actuator separately rather than aggregating them into a single publisher.

There examples of building messages consisting of other message types in the `geometry_msgs` library: https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/geometry_msgs/html/index-msg.html. In particular "Polygon", "PolygonStamped", and "PoseWithCovariance" might be good examples.

Comment: Thanks, I meant how do I create an array of messages, ex array of custom message but it looks like the syntax is the same as the base types allowed.  Wish the documentation was better though.